# Sed replace at second occurrence

Tags: regex, bash, sed, non-greedy

I want to remove a pattern with sed, only at second occurence. Here is what I want, remove a pattern but on second occurrence.

What's in the file.csv:

```
a,Name(null)abc.csv,c,d,Name(null)abc.csv,f
a,Name(null)acb.csv,c,d,Name(null)acb.csv,f
a,Name(null)cba.csv,c,d,Name(null)cba.csv,f
```

Output wanted:

```
a,Name(null)abc.csv,c,d,Name,f
a,Name(null)acb.csv,c,d,Name,f
a,Name(null)cba.csv,c,d,Name,f
```

This is what i tried:

```
sed -r 's/(\(null)\).*csv//' file.csv
```

The problem here is that the regex is too greedy, but i cannot make is stop.
I also tried this, to skip the first occurrence of "null":

```
sed -r '0,/null/! s/(\(null)\).*csv//' file.csv
```

Also tried but the greedy regex is still the problem.

```
sed -r 's/(\(null)\).*csv//2' file.csv
```

I've read that `?` can make the regex "lazy", but I cannot make it workout.

```
sed -r 's/(\(null)\).*?csv//' file.csv
```

Comment: If you may have 3 or more `(null)`s and you still want to only remove the 2nd occurrence, I think it would be easier to do with perl, using `.*?` instead of `.*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more robust **awk** solution:

Extended sample file `input.csv`:

```
12,Name(null)randomstuff.csv,2,3,Name(null)randomstuff.csv, false,Name(null)randomstuff.csv
12,Name(null)AotherRandomStuff.csv,2,3,Name(null)AotherRandomStuff.csv, false,Name(null)randomstuff.csv
12,Name(null)alphaNumRandom.csv,2,3,Name(null)alphaNumRandom.csv, false,Name(null)randomstuff.csv
```

---

The job:

```
awk -F, '{ c=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/\(null\)/ && c++==1) sub(/\(null\).*/,"",$i) }1' OFS=',' input.csv
```

The output:

```
12,Name(null)randomstuff.csv,2,3,Name, false,Name(null)randomstuff.csv
12,Name(null)AotherRandomStuff.csv,2,3,Name, false,Name(null)randomstuff.csv
12,Name(null)alphaNumRandom.csv,2,3,Name, false,Name(null)randomstuff.csv
```

Comment: Great this is Working just fine! I'll have to check out more on awk tool!

Answer (score 21):

`sed` does provide an easy way to specify which match to be replaced. Just add the number after delimiters

```
$ sed 's/(null)[^.]*\.csv//2' ip.csv
a,Name(null)abc.csv,c,d,Name,f
a,Name(null)acb.csv,c,d,Name,f
a,Name(null)cba.csv,c,d,Name,f

$ # or [^,] if there are no , within fields
$ sed 's/(null)[^,]*//2' ip.csv
a,Name(null)abc.csv,c,d,Name,f
a,Name(null)acb.csv,c,d,Name,f
a,Name(null)cba.csv,c,d,Name,f
```

Also, no need to escape `()` when not using extended regular expressions

Comment: I've tried it if you look closer in my post. The problem was the Greedy Regex. I had to change `.*` with `[^,]*` like in your example. Thank you.

Comment: well I didn't notice that you had tried `//1` (later edited to `//2`) ... so you were only put off by greedy issue... easy to solve in this case as there are workarounds with `[^,]` or `[^.]`... for generic case you might need proper csv parsers available in perl/python/etc

Comment: You are right, i could of done this with pyexcel which i use in my script. Didn't thought about that!

Comment: ahhh, this is exactly what I needed as well, Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Execute:

```
awk '{sub(/.null.....csv,f/,",f")}1' file
```

And the output should be:

```
a,Name(null)abc.csv,c,d,Name,f
a,Name(null)acb.csv,c,d,Name,f
a,Name(null)cba.csv,c,d,Name,f
```