# How to replace only on second matching row using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

```
$ cat file
cat cat
dog cat
dog puppy
dog cat
```

Using sed:

```
$ sed 's/dog/big_dog/' my_file > new_file
$ cat new_file
cat cat 
big_dog cat
big_dog puppy
big_dog cat
```

My objective is to replace only the second `dog` with `big_dog` but that's not happening with:

```
$ sed 's/dog/big_dog/2' my_file > new_file
cat
dog cat
dog puppy
dog cat
```

How may I replace only the second occurrence, i.e.:

```
cat
dog cat
big_dog puppy
dog cat
```

Comment: always try to put your all requirements in a single post itself. Always try to select any of the provided answers as correct answer to close the thread, cheers.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: 1st thing you haven't covered your samples in code tags(please always do so). 2nd-always try to regard people who have answered by telling them in respective comments either their code worked or not, SO is only for guidance not for a free service. Hope this helps.

Comment: What does "covered your samples in code tags" mean?

Comment: [Sed replace at second occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46238843/608639), [replace nth occurrence of string in each line of a text file](https://superuser.com/q/143392/173513), [How to replace only the Nth occurrence of a pattern in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/181771/56041), [Use sed to use “find and replace” for each second occurrence](https://askubuntu.com/q/914868), etc.

Comment: here's your answer: `sed -i '0,/dog/! {0,/dog/ s/dog/big_dog/}' my_file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following `awk` may also help you here.

```
awk -v line=2 '$1=="dog" && ++count==line{$1="big_dog"} 1'  Input_file
```

In case of saving output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in above code.

***Explanation:***

```
awk -v line=2 '             ##Creating an awk variable line whose value is 2 here.
$1=="dog" && ++count==line{ ##Checking condition if $1 is dog and increasing variable count value is equal to value of line(then do following)
  $1="big_dog"}             ##Assigning $1 to big_dog here.
1                           ##awk works on method of condition then action so by mentioning 1 I am making condition TRUE here so by default action print of line will happen.
'  Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Answer (score 8):

`sed` for substitute the second occurrence is:

```
sed "/dog/ {n; :a; /dog/! {N; ba;}; s/dog/big_dog/; :b; n; $! bb}" your_file
```

---

Explanation:

```
/dog/ {           # find the first occurrence that match the pattern (dog)
  n               # print pattern space and read the next line
  :a              # 'a' label to jump to
  /dog/! {        # if pattern space not contains the searched pattern (second occurrence)
    N             # read next line and add it to pattern space
    ba            # jump back to 'a' label, to repeat this conditional check
  }               # after find the second occurrence...
  s/dog/big_dog/  # do the substitution
  :b              # 'b' label to jump to
  n               # print pattern space and read the next line
  $! bb           # while not the last line of the file, repeat from 'b' label
}
```

Note that last 3 commands are needed to print the rest of the file after found the second occurence, otherwise the substitution may be repeated for each even occurrences of the searched pattern.

Answer (score 7):

Like discussed in the comments, this one replaces match on the second row:

```
$ sed '2s/dog/big_dog/' your_file
dog cat
big_dog puppy
dog cat
```

To replace the second match with sed, use:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/dog/big_dog/2'   your_file_with_foo_on_first_row_to_demonstrate
foo
dog cat
big_dog puppy
dog cat
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.Can you point me to the documentation for this?

Comment: [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt), search for section _4 Addresses: selecting lines_.

Comment: Oh no. Is there a way to make this not specific to any line?

Comment: @BishwasMishra, try my `awk` code where I have put a variable which could have occurrence number and then it will change to that line as per occurrence, let me know if that helps you? Also please always mention your all requirements in a single time itself in your post.

Comment: this does sub on 2nd line, instead of 2nd Occurrence, doesn't it?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 so your cmd is same as `/pup/s/dog/big_&/` ?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  perhaps I should say sorry....  I posted that comment (just doing the 2nd line sub) regarding this answer. However, you thought I commented on your comment... And after I read your comment, I thought it was the reply by James.... so... you explained again your awk thing under this sed answer.. ^_*

Comment: Updated with a solution to replace the second occurrence with sed.

Answer (score -1):

Use below command to replace the word dog with big_dog in 2nd line.

```
# sed -i '2 s/dog/big_dog/g' my_file
# cat my_file
Output:-
dog cat
big_dog puppy
dog cat
```

Same If you want to replace from 2nd to 3rd, then you can use below command:-

```
# sed -i '2,3 s/dog/big_dog/g' my_file
```

Comment: Wanted it not to be line specific.