# Ansible: How to search and replace strings or replace block of text?

Tags: ansible

I have a file with that looks like this:

```xml
   <Resource name="X1" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>" password="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:yyyyy/yyyyy@yyyy:yyyy/yyyy"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"/>

   <Resource name="Y2" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>" password="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:yyyy/yyyyy@yyyyy:yyyyyy/yyyy"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"/>
```

I need to replace in the **second** `Resource` (`Y2`) the `driverClassName`, `url`, `validationQuery` values.

So it will look like this:

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/Y2" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>" password="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>"
              driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
              url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx:xxxx;databaseName=xxxxx;;"
              validationQuery="SELECT GETDATE()" testOnBorrow="true" testWhileIdle="true"/>
```

I'm puzzled how to do this in Ansible..  How should I do it?

My so-called "XML" has none valid tags (`<_PALCEHOLEDER_>`) so using `lxml`
is not going to work as it fails.

Comment: Have you attempted this in any way? Have a look at [xml module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/xml_module.html) if you haven't.

Comment: none , i have no idea how to do it in ansible , but you gave good start to look at

Comment: no good my original xml is not valid so lxml fail to load it 
i updated question

Answer (score 0):

For a variable file **`Y2.yml`**

```yaml
driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url: jdbc:sqlserver://db.example.com;databaseName=exampleDB;;
validationQuery: '"SELECT GETDATE()" testOnBorrow="true" testWhileIdle="true"'
```

**1)** An option would be using the [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) and a template file **`config.xml.j2`**

```xml
<Resource name="X1" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     username="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>" password="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>"
     driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
     url="jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@db.example.com:1521/exampleDB"
     validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"/>

<Resource name="Y2" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     username="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>" password="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>"
     driverClassName="{{ Y2.driverClassName }}"
     url="{{ Y2.url }}"
     validationQuery={{ Y2.validationQuery }}/>
```

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - include_vars:
      file: Y2.yml
      name: Y2

  - debug:
      var: Y2

  - template:
      src: config.xml.j2
      dest: config.xml
```

will result into an output of a **`config.xml`** file with content

```xml
<Resource name="X1" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     username="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>" password="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>"
     driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
     url="jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@db.example.com:1521/exampleDB"
     validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"/>

<Resource name="Y2" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     username="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>" password="<_PALCEHOLEDER_>"
     driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
     url="jdbc:sqlserver://db.example.com;databaseName=exampleDB;;"
     validationQuery="SELECT GETDATE()" testOnBorrow="true" testWhileIdle="true"/>
```

**2)** A second less preferable option could be to to use the [`lineinfile` module – Manage lines in text files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) module

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ Y2 | dict2items }}"

  - lineinfile:
      path: config.xml
      insertafter: 'name="Y2"'
      search_string: '{{ item.key }}='
      line: '     {{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}'
    loop: "{{ Y2 | dict2items }}"
```

Please take note that in this example you would have to adopt and adjust the approach and work out a solution for the currently missing `/>` at the end.

**3)** A third, the least recommended option could be to inline "edit" the file with `sed` through the `shell` module

```yaml
  - shell:
      cmd: sed -i '2s/{{ item.key }}=.*/{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}/g' config.xml
    loop: "{{ Y2 | dict2items }}"
```

Please take note that in this example you would have to adopt and adjust the approach and work out a solution for the `url` replacement.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: Canonical way to modify/add multiple lines in a config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77706859/6771046)

**Thanks To**

- [How to replace only on second matching row using `sed`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624719/6771046)