# sed replace second occurrence in file not working

Tags: bash, sed, centos

I'm using centos 7. sed command to replace **second** occurrence not working to me.
I tried the following solutions:

- [Sed replace at second occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46238843/sed-replace-at-second-occurrence)
- [Sed/Awk to delete second occurence of string - platform independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815099/sed-awk-to-delete-second-occurence-of-string-platform-independent)
- [sed: How to delete second match in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785309/sed-how-to-delete-second-match-in-a-file)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18303/sed-delete-all-occurrences-of-a-string-except-the-first-one

The **file**:

```
this
foo
is
a test
file
this
foo
```

I am trying to run:

```
sed 's/foo/bar/2g' file
sed 's/foo/bar/2' file
sed -i 's/foo/bar/2g' file
```

I wish to replace all occurrences of "foo" with "bar" from the second one.

Comment: The answer you tried to emulate is aimed at replacing the second occurrence of the pattern *in each line*.  It contains no mechanism or logic for tracking occurrences of the pattern across multiple lines.

Comment: Do you want to replace *only* the second appearance in the whole file?  Or else, maybe every even-numbered appearance?  Or the second and all subsequent appearances?  Can you assume that there will be at least two appearances? Can you assume that there will be exactly two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for  you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/foo/bar/2' file
```

Slurps the whole for file into the pattern space and replaces the second occurrence of `foo` with `bar`.

Alternative:

```
sed 'H;$!d;x;s/.//;s/foo/bar/2' file
```

Comment: The first one is perfectly good.

Comment: For all occurrences from the second and thereafter use the `g` flag on the substitution command.

Answer (score 2):

This will perform a substitution on the second and all subsequent lines containing the specified pattern (`/foo/`):

```sh
sed ':1; /foo/! { n; b1 }; :2; n; s/foo/bar/; b2' file
```

It has two parts:

- `:1; /foo/! { n; b1 };` is a loop, reading lines and outputting them unchanged until the first is encountered that matches `/foo/`.
- `:2; n; s/foo/bar/; b2` is a loop that repeatedly outputs the current line, reads the next and performs the substitution `s/foo/bar/`.  The substitution is a harmless no-op for lines that do not contain the pattern.

The first match to the pattern is the current line at the beginning of the second loop, so it is output unchanged when second loop first executes its `n` command.